# How to reduce an unknown size data into a fixed size data? Please read details

Tags: statistics, data-science

Example:
Given n number of images marked 1 to n where n is unknown, I can calculate a property of every image which is a scalar quantity. Now I have to represent this property of all images in a fixed size vector (say 5 or 10).

One naive approach can be this vector- [avg max min std_deviation]
And I also want to include the effect of relative positions of those images.

Answer (score 0):

What your are looking for is called `feature extraction`.

There are many techniques for the same, for images:
For your purpose try:

1. [PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)
2. [Auto-encoders](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html)
3. Convolutional Auto-encoders, [1](https://pgaleone.eu/neural-networks/deep-learning/2016/12/13/convolutional-autoencoders-in-tensorflow/) & [2](https://gist.github.com/naotokui/b9fb93b8dba534b55a140e8c88ce07f5)

You could also look into conventional (old) methods like SIFT, HOG, Edge Detection, but they all will need an extra step for making them to a smaller-fixed size.